# TypeScript: How to use the value of one property as the type for another?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following example, the goal here is to be able to read the value of `aHandler.MessageType` and be able to infer what `aHandler.Callback` can receive as an argument. So here, if `aHandler.MessageType` is `EMessageType.Ping`, we can only use `EMessageType.Ping` as an argument to the callback. This is a trivial example but you could imagine using `EMessageType.Ping` instead as an argument to some generic message type.

Currently, TypeScript will use the value of `TType = EMessageType.Ping | EMessageType.Pong` for `TGenericCallback`, which makes sense. What I am trying to do is set `TGenericCallback<valueof THandler.MessageType>`. Such that once I prove `MessageType === EMessageType.Ping`, the callback will update it's type to `TGenericCallback<EMessageType.Ping>`. My intuition is that this can't be done cleanly in typescript without something like a `valueof` operator?

```js
enum EMessageType
{
    Ping = "Ping",
    Pong = "Pong",
}

type TGenericCallback<T> = (aMessage: T) => void;

type THandler<TType> =
{
    MessageType: TType;
    Callback: TGenericCallback<TType>;
};

function RegisterHandler(aHandler: THandler<EMessageType.Ping | EMessageType.Pong>): void
{
    if (aHandler.MessageType === EMessageType.Ping)
    {
        aHandler.Callback(EMessageType.Ping);  // Supported
        aHandler.Callback(EMessageType.Pong);  // Unsupported
    }
    else if (aHandler.MessageType === EMessageType.Pong)
    {
        aHandler.Callback(EMessageType.Ping);  // Unsupported
        aHandler.Callback(EMessageType.Pong);  // Supported
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
function RegisterHandler(
  aHandler: THandler<EMessageType.Ping> | THandler<EMessageType.Pong>
): void
```

---

#### Explanation

All that you need to do to fix this is to change the way that you define your `aHandler` variable.  Right now it is a `THandler` of the union `EMessageType.Ping | EMessageType.Pong`.  This means that both the `MessageType` and the `Callback` can be for either "Ping" or "Pong".  We don't know that they match each other.  Therefore refining the type of `aHandler.MessageType` does not refine the type of `aHandler.Callback`.

You should define `aHandler` as `THandler<EMessageType.Ping> | THandler<EMessageType.Pong>` instead.  This is a union of two `THandlers` rather than a `THandler` of a union.  Now if we know that the `aHandler.MessageType` is "Ping" then we know that `aHandler` can only be `THandler<EMessageType.Ping>` and `aHandler.Callback` can only be `TGenericCallback<EMessageType.Ping>`.  You'll get the errors that you want on your "Unsupported" types.

---

If there are lots of members in the enum then you would not want to write out this union of `THandlers` by hand.  Instead you can use a mapped type:

```
type HandlerUnion = {
    [E in EMessageType]: THandler<E>
}[EMessageType]
```

this evaluates to the same type as before:

```
type HandlerUnion = THandler<EMessageType.Ping> | THandler<EMessageType.Pong>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogssAzoghgc2AFQJ4AdgBQA3gVGVAAoCWIaUAvFAETW1MA0p5FA9rQ815tOAXwIEALnmBRMAcVDAATlQDGAYRQAbLQCMUqgNYAeTAD4BAChQJk6YAC5ZASgYWAbjyoATANzipfFkACRQQby1lUxx8C3piLjJbVAwYx1k0-3IoTR19Iyd5RRUNbT0DE0w0s38Rf0lpKFDwyKUAVRAqPgESbIBtGCgaWGT7NIBdQuaIqJgzAhEB0dTpcfEAMzAQVQkukCgAJWA0KkQJZWnW60vlJxv2zr5nJ08fBOyqdahrsJmlADpllhGvRQSMkClgfh-qw0M5ElBetlyCh7v9cuUjJZ4BCxtIYTQ4b4yAB6ElQADKYFwuB4SnO3gR2VRv1a6LK%20UM2KBaRhfCJpPJHUQ1Np9OAjOyYmywC0iBkn2%20LJaykBuJWQVBjBxdg1wD5tHh2SRyKgyr%207LyFW56qh%20thzmJUDJUGForpDKZKLRGM5Nt1doNAud5KpNI9EoRYhEQA)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing out the logical error in my union, also thankful for the HandlerUnion type, that's an area of typescript I'm definitely less familiar with